# Swap every pair of bits in byte

Tags: byte, swap, bit

This was a question asked by an NVIDIA representative at a career fair:

Write small, efficient code to swap every pair of bits inside a byte; for example, `10 11 01 10` should become `01 11 10 01`.

Is there any more "efficient" way to do this than by doing a `for` loop through every other index? My code was small, but I can't think of how much more "efficient" this could possibly get than a loop... I'm guessing there might be a way to use XOR to avoid a loop, but I can't figure it out.

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could use a 256-entry lookup table.

Alternatively, `((x & 0x55) << 1) | ((x & 0xAA) >> 1)`.

Comment: +1. If it's speed you want, the lookup table is the answer. It uses 256 bytes for a lookup table but, as with most optimisations, it's a space/time trade-off. If you don't want to waste that space, you're unlikely to get any faster than a couple of shifts and bit operations.

Comment: +1 I think it's the second solution, since it's the most concise, and very efficient... argh, so easy and yet so hard. :(

Comment: The lookup table is slow on modern architectures, so the above idea is by far preferred. In the lookup-table a cache miss quickly is 10-20 isns - more if we miss the 2nd level cache as well. In contrast the above is (SHIFT + AND) and (SHIFT + AND) which can be run in parallel followed by a dependent OR. So with two execution units it is 3 times you have to traverse them. No lookup table can beat that and adds memory pressure.

Answer (score 14):

Something like this should work

```
(i >> 1) & 01010101 + (i << 1) & 10101010
```

`i >> 1` shifts everything by 1 bit to the right, and `& 01010101` leaves only bits at even position.
Second part deals with odd bit positions in the same fasion.

Not sure how efficient it, though.

Comment: +1 This is darn clever, thanks... I was thinking of some way to use bit shifts but couldn't figure it out. Cool!! :)

Comment: Yes, I prefer the | operator to the + operator but the same solution. And of course your code is pseudo for the base-2 representation.

Answer (score 2):

Without lookup table (or to generate the thing in the first place) you can also:

- shift left and AND with left-bit mask (10101010)
- shift right and AND with right-bit mask (01010101)
- OR results together.

10 11 01 10

shifted left is 01 10 11 00
masked with 10101010 gives us 00 10 10 00

shifted right (original) is
01 01 10 11
masked with 01010101 gives us 01 01 00 01

OR our results together

01 11 10 01

So in C or C++ you could do

```
unsigned char bitswap( unsigned char uch )
{
   return ((uch<<1) & 0xAA) | (uch>>1) & 0x55 );
}
```

Just run that for all values from 0x00 to 0xff (ensure your loop terminates!) to generate your "table".

Comment: Thank you for the explanation!

Answer (score 1):

Table lookup (unless there's some particular NVIDA-specific solution he was looking for).

Comment: It wasn't looking for an NVIDIA-specific solution, but it was looking for fast *and* small code... would the table lookup solution count? (although admittedly I didn't think of it...)

Comment: @Mehrdad: Table lookup is just a "first thing that comes to mind" with these kinds of problems. There certainly might be a better, clever bit hack. You could also consider a smaller 16 byte (or even 8 byte maybe) table combined with some shift/mask operations to look up 4 bits at a time.  I'm not sure where the sweet spot might be.

Answer (score 1):

For 32-bit interger in java..

```
public int swapOddEvenbits(int x)
{
   return (  ((x & 0xaaaaaaaa) >> 1 | ((x & 0X55555555) << 1) );

}
```

If you are working with 64-bit, you would need to change mask..

Answer (score 0):

Since there are only 256 possible combinations in a byte, this seems like a good candidate for using a lookup table based solution for any time when continuous execution speed is more important than the inital precompute and/or total memory utilisation.

For example:

```
lookupTable[00000000] = 00000000
lookupTable[00000001] = 00000010
lookupTable[00000010] = 00000001
...
```

Comment: Definitely not I agree, but remember that small code is not always efficient and efficient code is not always small.

Comment: Cache misses is a problem with lookup tables in general. For things this small, it is easier to just compute the result I think.